# Finding the minimum value of $(x_1-x_2)^2 +\left(\frac{9}{x_1} - \sqrt{1-x_2^2}\right)^2$ by using trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Find the minimum value of the given function by using trigonometry
> $$(x_1-x_2)^2 + \left(\dfrac{9}{x_1} - \sqrt{1-x_2^2}\right)^2$$

I know the distance formula method but is there any other suitable method to solve this? I’m thinking along the lines of trigonometry or AM-GM inequality.

Comment: What do you mean by distance formula method?

Comment: Notice that both curves are (diagonally) symmetric about the origin.  The minimum distance between the curves occurs along lines that are perpendicular to both curves simultaneously.  That will be the distance between the intersection points of the curves with the line $ \ y \ = \ x \ \ $ (conveniently enough!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Expand as usual, and using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality: $f(x_1,x_2) = x_1^2 - 2x_1x_2 + \dfrac{81}{x_1^2} - \dfrac{18\sqrt{1-x_2^2}}{x_1}+1 = 1+x_1^2+\dfrac{81}{x_1^2} - 2\left(x_1x_2+\dfrac{9\sqrt{1-x_2^2}}{x_1}\right)\ge 1+x_1^2+\dfrac{81}{x_1^2} - 2\sqrt{x_1^2+\dfrac{81}{x_1^2}}\sqrt{x_2^2+(1-x_2^2)} = 1 + y^2- 2y = g(y)$, with $y = \sqrt{x_1^2+\dfrac{81}{x_1^2}}\ge 3\sqrt{2}$ by AM-GM inequality. Thus the problem reduces to finding the min value of $g(y) = y^2-2y+1, y \ge 3\sqrt{2}$. We have again: $g(y) = (y-1)^2 \ge (3\sqrt{2}-1)^2= 19-6\sqrt{2}$, and thus $f(x_1,x_2)_{\text{min}} = 19-6\sqrt{2}$ and this min value achieved when $x_1 = \pm 3, \dfrac{x_1}{x_2}=\dfrac{\dfrac{9}{x_1}}{\sqrt{1-x_2^2}}\implies x_1 = \pm 3, x_2 = \sqrt{1-x_2^2}\implies x_2^2=1-x_2^2\implies x_2 = \pm \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Comment: Mind-blowing ! .

Comment: Do not vandalize people's answers. I have rolled this back to its previous state.

Comment: PERFECT SOLUTION